# Pasar el valor de una variable desde una funcion a otra funcion en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, clase

Estoy comenzando mis estudios en Python y necesito hacer este código para mi clase.

Basicamente consiste en el registro de los trabajadores de una compañia para calcular su salario/sueldo, aplicando algunos descuentos y bonos/incentivos.

En la opción 4 del menu, debo imprimir todos los Rut/ID registrados con su respectivo sueldo final.

Necesito poner `SueldoDescontado` que esta en la funcion `Def Calcular_Sueldo()` *dentro* de la funcion `Def Liquidaciones_Rut`

Me dijeron que lo definiera como una `Class` y lo agregara al registro List[].

PD: si defino `SueldoDescontado` como *global* me imprime el mismo valor para todas las Rut/ID.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

[Aquie esta mi codigo en PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/vLX5cDJY)

```
Lista = [] #<----- Array


Mess = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril','mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre',
        'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre',
        'ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE']

Rank =  ['novato', 'experto', 'supervisor', 'administrativo',
         'Novato', 'Experto', 'Supervisor', 'Administrativo',
         'NOVATO', 'EXPERTO', 'SUPERVISOR', 'ADMINISTRATIVO']

SistemaSalud = ['a', 'b', 'c',
                'A', 'B', 'C']



class Trabajador: #Class <----
    Mes = '' 
    Año = 0
    Rut = ''
    Nombre = ''
    Categoria = ''
    DiasOff = 0
    AFP = ''
    SSalud = ''
    SueldoBruto = 0
    SueldoDescontado = 0

def Ingresar_Datos():
    Elementos = int(input('Ingrese cantidad de trabajadores que desea agregar: \n')) #<--- How many people do you want to add
    for Trabajadores in range(Elementos):
        dato = Trabajador()

        while True:
            Nombre = input("Ingrese un nombre: ") #<--- Name
            if vacio(Nombre):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            else:
                dato.Nombre = Nombre
                break

        while True:
            Rut = input('Ingrese Rut: ') # <---- ID Number
            if vacio(Rut):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            else:
                dato.Rut = Rut
                break

        while True:
            Mes = input('Ingrese mes: ') # <---- Month when start at work
            if vacio(Mes):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            elif Mes in Mess:
                dato.Mes = Mes
                break
            else:
                print('Mes invalido')


        while True:
            Año = input('Ingrese año: ') # <---- Year when start at work
            if vacio(Año):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            else:
                dato.Año = Año
                break

        while True:
            AFP = input('Ingrese AFP: ') # <---- NVM just a company name can be put here, not relevant
            if vacio(AFP):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            else:
                dato.AFP = AFP
                break

        while True:
            SSalud = input('Sistema de salud A B o C\nDigite opcion: ') # <---- System Health, Here is A, B or C, This make a discount%
            if vacio(SSalud):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            elif SSalud in SistemaSalud:
                dato.SSalud = SSalud
                break
            else:
                print ('::::::::::::::::::::ERROR Opcion Invalida::::::::::::::::::::')


        while True:
            Categoria = input('Categoria; Novato, Supervisor, Experto o Administrativo: ') # <---- Worker rank, Expert have a 2xBonus for 0 days off
            if vacio(Categoria):
                print ('No puede dejar el campo vacio')
            elif Categoria in Rank:
                dato.Categoria = Categoria
                break
            else:
                print ('::::::::::::::::::::ERROR Categoria invalida::::::::::::::::::::')


        while True:
                DiasOff = input('Ingrese cantidad de dias de ausencia: ') #<------ Days of absence, 0 days have a bonus$
                if dato.DiasOff < 0 or dato.DiasOff > 30:
                    print ('Dias de ausencia no puede ser negativo o mayor a 30')
                else:
                    dato.DiasOff = DiasOff
                    break


        while True:
            try:
                SueldoBruto = int(input('Ingrese sueldo bruto: ')) # <------- Gross Salary
                if dato.SueldoBruto < 0:
                    print ('El monto del sueldo bruto no puede ser negativo')
                else:
                    dato.SueldoBruto = SueldoBruto
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print('error')

        print("------------------------------------------------")
        Lista.append(dato)


def vacio(x):
    if x and x.strip():
        return False
    return True 


def Calcular_Sueldo():
    Bono = 50000 #<-------- Bonus for 0 Days of absence
    for Trabajadores in Lista:
        print('Nombre trabajador: ',Trabajadores.Nombre,'\n')

        if Trabajadores.DiasOff == '0' and Trabajadores.Categoria == ('experto') or Trabajadores.DiasOff == '0' and Trabajadores.Categoria == ('Experto') or Trabajadores.DiasOff == '0' and Trabajadores.Categoria == ('EXPERTO'):
            SueldoBono = Trabajadores.SueldoBruto + Bono*2 #<-------- There is if 0 days absence and rank experto, 2xBonus
            print('Sueldo bruto + Bono (Experto) por 0 faltas: ',SueldoBono)


        elif Trabajadores.DiasOff == '0': #<-------- Bonus for 0 Days of absence, nvm about rank here
            SueldoBono = Trabajadores.SueldoBruto + Bono
            print('Sueldo bruto + Bono por 0 faltas: ',SueldoBono)


        else:
            SueldoBono = Trabajadores.SueldoBruto #<-------- No bonus for days absence
            print('Tiene faltas/ausencia, no tiene derecho a Bono: ',SueldoBono)


        DctoAFP = SueldoBono - (SueldoBono * 0.1) #<-------- This makes a 10% descuento for AFP, the nvm'company name
        print('Sueldo bruto + Recorte del 10% por AFP ',Trabajadores.AFP,': ',DctoAFP)



        if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'a' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'A': #<-------- If Sistem Health is A, make a 5,7% discount
            DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 5.7
            print('Recorte del sistema de salud A: ',DctoSalud)
            SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud #<-------------------------- This Variable --------- !"#$"!#%!"#%!#"%"#$%$"#----------
            print('Total a pagar: ',SueldoDescontado)





        if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'b' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'B': #<-------- If Sistem Health is B, make a 6.1% discount
            DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 6.1
            print('Recorte del sistema de salud B: ',DctoSalud)
            SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud #<-------------------------- This Variable --------- !"#$"!#%!"#%!#"%"#$%$"#----------
            print('Total a pagar: ',SueldoDescontado)





        if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'c' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'C': #<-------- If Sistem Health is C, make a 6.5% discount
            DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 6.5
            print('Recorte del sistema de salud C: ',DctoSalud)
            SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud #<-------------------------- This Variable --------- !"#$"!#%!"#%!#"%"#$%$"#----------
            print('Total a pagar: ',SueldoDescontado)




    print('--------------------------------------')

def Liquidaciones_Rut(): #<------- Here i need to print all the ID's number's with his Final Salary (SueldoDescontado)
    for Trabajadores in Lista:
        print('Rut: ',Trabajadores.Rut,'Total a pagar: $',SueldoDescontado) #<----- To here --------- !"#$"!#%!"#%!#"%"#$%$"#----------




def Listar_Empleados(): #<------------------ Here just print the names of all workers
    for Trabajadores in Lista:
        print("Empleados registrados: ", Trabajadores.Nombre)






opcion = 7
while (opcion != 6):
    print(' ========== Administracion NovaVision ========== ')
    print('Menu')
    print('1.- Ingresar Datos') #<-------------------------- Enter Data
    print('2.- Calcular Sueldo') #<-------------------------- Calculate Salary
    print('3.- Listar Empleados') #<----------------------------- List employees (by his name)
    print('4.- Mostrar Liquidaciones por RUT') # <--------- List numbers ID with his Respective Salary
    print('5.- Salir')
    opcion = int(input('Ingrese su opcion: '))
    if (opcion == 1):
        Ingresar_Datos() 
    elif (opcion == 2):
        Calcular_Sueldo()
    elif (opcion == 3):
       Listar_Empleados()
    elif (opcion == 4):
        Liquidaciones_Rut()
    elif (opcion == 5):
        print('Saliendo .. ')
    else:
        print ('Opcion no valida')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio, has hecho un gran trabajo dentro del alcance de tu aplicación y realmente me pregunto porque no has podido lograrlo, si lo que te falta es algo que hiciste en todas partes de tu script menos en `SueldoDescontado`.

De cualquier manera, la respuesta es la siguiente:

Lo único que te ha faltado hacer es guardar la variable `SueldoDescontado` en cada objeto `Trabajadores` de la lista que recorres cuando invocas la función `Calcular_Sueldo()`. Te hacía el comentario al principio, porque lo has hecho a lo largo de todo tu script, pero por alguna razón en esta parte lo has olvidado. Tendría que quedar algo así: (solo pondré las partes del código que necesitan cambios)

1.Cambios en la función `Calcular_Sueldo()`

```
 if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'a' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'A': 
        DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 5.7
        print('Recorte del sistema de salud A: ',DctoSalud)
        Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud
        #SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud 
        print('Total a pagar: ',Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado)

 if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'b' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'B': 
        DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 6.1
        print('Recorte del sistema de salud B: ',DctoSalud)
        Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud
        #SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud 
        print('Total a pagar: ',Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado)

 if Trabajadores.SSalud == 'c' or Trabajadores.SSalud == 'C': 
        DctoSalud = (DctoAFP/100) * 6.5
        print('Recorte del sistema de salud C: ',DctoSalud)
        Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud
        #SueldoDescontado = DctoAFP - DctoSalud 
        print('Total a pagar: ',Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado)
```

Como puedes observar, hacemos referencia al objeto `Trabajadores` y a su propiedad `SueldoDescontado`, en vez de hacerlo solo a una variable como lo estabas haciendo antes (ver linea comentada). En la función `print` que sigue a continuación ya no hacemos referencia solo a la variable (como lo hacias antes) sino al objeto con su propiedad.

2. Cambios en la funcion `Liquidaciones_Rut()`

   ```
   def Liquidaciones_Rut(): 
       for Trabajadores in Lista:
           print('Rut: ',Trabajadores.Rut,'Total a pagar: $',Trabajadores.SueldoDescontado)
   ```

En este caso es aun mas evidente. En vez de intentar llamar a una variable `SueldoDescontado` que no ha sido declara en ninguna parte, llamamos al objeto que esta siendo iterado y obtenemos su propiedad `SueldoDescontado` que previamente hemos guardado en la función `Calcular_Sueldo()`

Eso deberia solucionar tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! No sabes lo bien que se siente leer tus palabras!

Creeme que lo habia intentado, con un append al final y nada, poniendo dato = trabajador() entre lineas para guardar el dato alli y se me iba en un bucle infinito

Tu correccion me a funcionado de maravilla!. Veo que aun cosas que me faltan por comprender, asi que seguire practicando!

Comment: De nada Fabio. Que bueno que te ha servido mi respuesta y gracias por marcarla como aceptada. Sigue practicando y cuando te sientas en la capacidad contribuye a la comunidad respondiendo a otras preguntas. Saludos